# FB.UI display dialog is blocked in IE9 in a iframe app, 'only secure content is displayed'

Tags: internet-explorer, facebook, internet-explorer-9

Here is my code, it works fine in IE 7, 8, but blocked in IE 9

```
FB.ui(
           {
               display: 'dialog',
               method: 'feed',
               name: Resource.WallPost.Title,
               link: Resource.WallPost.Url,
               picture: Resource.WallPost.PictureUrl,
               caption: '',
               description: Resource.WallPost.Description,
               message: ''
           },
           function (response) {
               if (response && response.post_id) {               
               } else {               
               }
           }
         );
```

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons, IE9 blocks insecure content in secure subframes. The Facebook team is currently working on addressing this in their API.

Comment: Eric: have you heard any progress on this since May?  I've just encountered this issue on my site today.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable this annoying prompt in IE9. [This article](http://socialdiets.wordpress.com/2011/04/24/remove-disable-facebook-prompt-%E2%80%9Conly-secure-content-is-displayed%E2%80%9D-popups-in-internet-explorer-9-ie9/) shows how to do that.

Comment: There are two problems with this solution. First, it requires every user of your site to change IE default settings. Second, it makes browsing less secure.

Comment: Yes, I totally agree - this is only a workaround. The real solution would be to do it right and load only secure content when working in secure environments (and force webdevs to follow that)...

Answer (score 0):

When I set FB._https = true, then I get the mixed content warning.

When I set FB._https = false, I get the mixed content warning there, too.

At this point in IE9, I'm always getting the warning.